# MongoDB count related documents (3 levels)

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I need to fast count related documents.

So, I have four collections

groups

```
{ "_id" : "g1", "name" : "group1" }
{ "_id" : "g2", "name" : "group2" }
```

courses

```
{ "_id" : "c1", "name" : "course1", "group_id" : "g1" }
{ "_id" : "c2", "name" : "course2", "group_id" : "g2" }
```

topics

```
{ "_id" : "t1", "name" : "top1c11", "course_id" : "c1" }
{ "_id" : "t2", "name" : "top1c12", "course_id" : "c1" }
{ "_id" : "t3", "name" : "top1c21", "course_id" : "c2" }
```

lessons

```
{ "_id" : "l1", "name" : "lesson111", "topic_id" : "t1" }
{ "_id" : "l2", "name" : "lesson112", "topic_id" : "t1" }
{ "_id" : "l3", "name" : "lesson121", "topic_id" : "t2" }
{ "_id" : "l4", "name" : "lesson211", "topic_id" : "t3" }
```

I need count all lessons of the specific group.

I tried to run the following aggregation, but I didn't wait for an response. (But it working for small amount of data)

```
db.getCollection('lessons').aggregate([
{
    "$lookup": {
        "from": "topics",
        "let": { "topicId": "$topic_id" },
        "pipeline": [
            { 
                "$match": { "$expr": { "$eq": [ "$_id", "$$topicId" ] } } 
            },
            {
                "$lookup": {
                    "from": "courses",
                    "let": { "courseId": "$topic_id" },
                    "pipeline": [
                        { "$match": { "$expr": { "$eq": [ "$course_id", "$$courseId" ] } } },
                    ],
                    "as": "course"
                },
            },
            {
                "$unwind": "$course"
            }

        ],
        "as": "topic"
    },
},
{
    "$unwind" : "$topic"
},
{
    "$match": {
        "topic.course.group_id" : "g1"
    }
},
{
    $group: {
        _id: "$course",
        "amount": {$sum:1},
    }
}
])
```

I believe this aggregation can be optimized. But I don`t sure that is a good approach to use aggregation framework for such purpose. If so, how can I optimize the aggregation.

Size of collections (test data):

- courses: 30000
- topics: 200000
- lessons: 30000000

Now I use simple nested loops in my code to count lessons. This takes 10 seconds (for 3000 topics of the certain group).

Answer (score 0):

Query1

- not nested lookups (lookup and unwind)
- match the group
- lookup and unwind 3x, last lookup only counts the lessons, and uses pipeline lookup
- group by group `_id`, to get the total lessons

Indexes that you need (all the foreignField)

- `courses.group_id`
- `topics.course_id`
- `lessons.topic_id`

[Test code here](https://cmql.org/play/?q=70448283-m)

```js
groups.aggregate(
[{"$match":{"_id":"g1"}},
 {"$lookup":
  {"from":"courses",
   "localField":"_id",
   "foreignField":"group_id",
   "as":"courses"}},
 {"$unwind":"$courses"},
 {"$lookup":
  {"from":"topics",
   "localField":"courses._id",
   "foreignField":"course_id",
   "as":"topics"}},
 {"$unwind":"$topics"},
 {"$lookup":
  {"from":"lessons",
   "localField":"topics._id",
   "foreignField":"topic_id",
   "pipeline":
   [{"$group":{"_id":null, "lessons":{"$sum":1}}},
    {"$set":{"id":"$_id", "_id":"$$REMOVE"}}],
   "as":"lessons"}},
 {"$set":
  {"lessons":
   {"$cond":
    [{"$eq":["$lessons", []]}, 0,
     {"$arrayElemAt":["$lessons.lessons", 0]}]}}},
 {"$group":{"_id":"$_id", "totalLessons":{"$sum":"$lessons"}}}])
```

Query2

- nested lookups (without unwind)
- code is the same, just nested

[Test code here](https://cmql.org/play/?q=70448283-1-m)

```js
groups.aggregate(
[{"$match":{"_id":"g1"}},
 {"$lookup":
  {"from":"courses",
   "localField":"_id",
   "foreignField":"group_id",
   "pipeline":
   [{"$lookup": 
     {"from":"topics",
      "localField":"_id",
      "foreignField":"course_id",
      "pipeline":
      [{"$lookup":
        {"from":"lessons",
         "localField":"_id",
         "foreignField":"topic_id",
         "pipeline":
         [{"$group":{"_id":null, "lessons":{"$sum":1}}},
          {"$set":{"id":"$_id", "_id":"$$REMOVE"}}],
         "as":"lessons"}},
       {"$set":
        {"lessons":
         {"$cond":
          [{"$eq":["$lessons", []]}, 0,
           {"$arrayElemAt":["$lessons.lessons", 0]}]}}}],
      "as":"topics"}},
    {"$project":
     {"_id":0, "totalLessons":{"$sum":"$topics.lessons"}}}],
   "as":"courses"}},
 {"$set":
  {"courses":"$$REMOVE",
   "totalLessons":
   {"$cond":
    [{"$eq":["$courses", []]}, 0,
     {"$arrayElemAt":["$courses.totalLessons", 0]}]}}}])
```

If you can send some feedback on which one was faster.
If for 1 group its very fast, maybe remove the match, to do it for all groups, or allow from match to pass more many groups.

Comment: I got an error `$lookup with 'pipeline' may not specify 'localField' or 'foreignField'"`

Comment: the above requires MongoDB 5, what version you havE?

Comment: oh, I use MongoDB 4.2.

Comment: Thank you for answer. I got the idea, and I try to adopt to my MongoDB version

Comment: [this](https://cmql.org/play/?q=1640181702901) will work on mongodb 4.2 , its the first query, just with let on the last lookup with pipeline. The second needs change in all lookups to work,  Indexes are the most important to have, else will be so slow.

Comment: I hadn't success with your last example. It gives me empty result. I modified your Query2 [with nested lookups](https://cmql.org/play/?q=1640196741976): this query works for me (processed about 1 second). But it does not work in online playground.

Comment: good it worked and 1 second its not very small but usable probably, on playground, collections have no names, so you refer to them as 1,2,3 .... , you can add names but i didn't on that example data. Also you had one extra comma on pipeline, and its strict. But i see one less join in your example check it to be sure its ok.

Answer (score 0):

Solution from [comment of Takis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70448283/mongodb-count-related-documents-3-levels/70449628?noredirect=1#comment124534842_70449628). Query1, adopted for 4.2

```
groups.aggregate(
[{"$match":{"_id":"g1"}},
 {"$lookup":
  {"from":"courses",
   "localField":"_id",
   "foreignField":"group_id",
   "as":"courses"}},
 {"$unwind":"$courses"},
 {"$lookup":
  {"from":"topics",
   "localField":"courses._id",
   "foreignField":"course_id",
   "as":"topics"}},
 {"$unwind":"$topics"},
 {"$lookup":
  {"from":"lessons",
   "pipeline":
   [{"$match":{"$expr":{"$eq":["$$ptopic", "$topic_id"]}}},
    {"$group":{"_id":null, "lessons":{"$sum":1}}},
    {"$set":{"id":"$_id", "_id":"$$REMOVE"}}],
   "as":"lessons",
   "let":{"ptopic":"$topics._id"}}},
 {"$set":
  {"lessons":
   {"$cond":
    [{"$eq":["$lessons", []]}, 0,
     {"$arrayElemAt":["$lessons.lessons", 0]}]}}},
 {"$group":{"_id":"$_id", "totalLessons":{"$sum":"$lessons"}}}])
```